# List of dictionaries being updated at once

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having an issue when I try to assign a value to a specific dictionary stored in a list of dictionaries is updated in every single dictionary in the list.  I am trying to track project completion steps by year, using the index of the list as the year of the project (except with 0=year 1, etc)

The list is created like so:

```
results = [{'status':{'reports': False, 'collection': False, 'workshops':False}, 'dates':{'reports':'', 'collection':'','workshops':''}}] * years
```

Where years is the number of project years passed in to the function.

I end up iterating over a dictionary of milestones looking for the completion milestones like this:

```
for milestone in data:
    if data['name'] == 'report completion':
        if data['completed'] == True:
            year = determineYear(x, y) #Pass some info from the milestone to determine which year of the project
            results[year]['status']['reports'] = True
            results[year]['dates']['reports'] = data['date']
```

The indenting didn't come through correctly, but I think you get the gist.

Everything seems to work correctly.  The `index(year)` is being calculated correctly, there's no extra looping or anything, but the list ends up looking like this:

```
[{'status': {'collection': False, 'workshops': False, 'reports': True}, 'dates': {'collection': '', 'workshops': '', 'reports': '03/10/2016'}}, 
{'status': {'collection': False, 'workshops': False, 'reports': True}, 'dates': {'collection': '', 'workshops': '', 'reports': '03/10/2016'}}, 
{'status': {'collection': False, 'workshops': False, 'reports': True}, 'dates': {'collection': '', 'workshops': '', 'reports': '03/10/2016'}}]
```

So the data is being stored in every dictionary in the list.  This is the first time I've tried a setup like this, so I may be missing something.

Comment: Moral: Don't use `* years` to multiply a list containing a mutable object.

Comment: Apparently my search skills failed.  Did not find that other answer :(